# How to prevent particles from partly going through the collision object?

Tags: particles

I have some particles that bounce on a collision object.

But when the particles fall on the collision, half of them pass through the surface.

like:

[image]

[image]

I just want to have a perfect bounce.

[image]

Comment: usually you place a non visible collision object, maybe same plane but just move it up and hide it to render... also consider subdividing it to improve detection... also remember that particles always collide as spheres

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You can use `Size Deflect` for this.**

Particles are points with no size and can be rendered "visually" as objects but when it comes to physics like collisions, they will still be considered as points so your collision plane is colliding with the particles this way.

There is an option to use size of the rendered form of the particle as a collision shape tho, it can be found under the Particle Settings in the `Physics` section and `Deflection`:

[image]

This option is unchecked by default for performance reasons but if you enable it, your particles will bounce off the plane the way you want them to.

With `Size Deflect` :

[image]

Without `Size Deflect` :

[image]

I found this on the answer posted by Michael_W on [this Blenderartists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-make-particles-not-pass-part-way-through-collision-object/507693).

Comment: Thank you for answering this!!